# Misterious wifi depends on BIOS

Tags: wireless, 20.04, bios, iwlwifi

**SOLVED!**
*disabling fast boot helped.*

I got a miniPC qotom j3060.
I installed fresh desktop 20.04 Ubuntu. Everything works normally before rebooting.
After rebooting there is no wifi in the system. lspci, iwconfig, lshw -C network do not show any traces of wireless devices.

However, if I enter the system setup (BIOS) before booting the device, even with no changes, wifi works again. What is going on? How can I fix it? Are there any workarounds? I want the machine to run headlessly as a home server.

Thank you in advance!

```
dima@qot:~$ uname -r
5.8.0-53-generic
```

AFTER entering BIOS (When wifi works):

```
dima@qot:~$ dmesg| grep iwl
[    4.886033] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.914154] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 3160-17.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.914528] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    5.000108] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[    5.020776] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: f4:06:69:d8:66:bb
[    5.146105] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    5.307813] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

```
dima@qot:~$ lspci | grep "Network controller"
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
```

```
dima@qot:~$ sudo mokutil –sb-state
[sudo] password for dima: 
This system doesn't support Secure Boot
```

```
dima@qot:~$ sudo lshw -C network
..........
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 83
       serial: f4:06:69:d8:66:bb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-53-generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 3160-17.ucode ip=192.168.69.125 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:125 memory:81200000-81201fff
```

Comment: Try disabling Fast Boot in UEFI ("BIOS").

Comment: Bro! You're my hero! It helped!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. This is not a forum. @DmitryMenshikov should post his comment as an answer and you should accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware detection and initialization happens during POST and depends on the motherboard's firmware, UEFI or BIOS.

The intermittent, inconsistent, detection of the WiFi device suggests a problem with UEFI and an update is probably in order. Please check the vendor's website for UEFI ("BIOS") updates.

**Meanwhile, disabling Fast Boot should avoid the problem.**